# How to parse user_defined_macro in regular function or PythonOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

We use managed Airflow inside a GCP project.

When I used BigQueryInsertJobOperator to execute queries in a query file, it used to automatically replace user_defined_macros in those files with the set value.

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator

with DAG(
    'test',
    schedule_interval = None,
    start_date = datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    user_defined_macros = {
        "MY_MACRO": "Hello World"
    }
) as dag:

    BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id = "my_task",
        configuration = {
                            "query": {
                                "query": "{% include '/queries/my_query.sql' %}",
                                "useLegacySql": False,
                            },
                        },
        dag = dag,
    )
```

Due to some reasons, I am switching to using a regular function or PythonOperator to execute those queries using a bigquery client. However, I am unable to figure out how to get the user_defined_macro to be parsed. The below is what I have so far, but doesn't work of course. Please help.

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery
from airflow.decorators import task

with DAG(
    'test',
    schedule_interval = None,
    start_date = datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    user_defined_macros = {
        "MY_MACRO": "Hello World"
    }
) as dag:
    
    @task
    def test():
        query = open('/home/airflow/gcs/dags/queries/my_query.sql').read()
        bq_client = bigquery.Client()
        bq_client.query(query).result()

    test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jinja2 templating to render your query.

```
from jinja2 import Template
...

@task
def test()
    with open(<your_templated_file_path>) as f:
        template = Template(f.read())

    query = template.render(
        **<dict_from_macros_or_other>,
    )
    bq_client = bigquery.Client()
    bq_client.query(query).result()
```

Comment: I have one more question in Airflow. Please answer if you can.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74244254/how-to-use-dynamic-task-mapping-with-taskgroups

Answer (score 1):

In Airflow operators, only the arguments defined in `template_fields` attribute are rendered by jinja, and in the `PythonOperator` (the operator used in your case), jinja renders `op_args` and `op_kwargs` arguments, and if your version is 2.4.1+, the argument `templates_dict` is rendered too. ([PR which fixed the problem](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/26390))

For Airflow 2.4.1+:

```py
    @task(templates_dict={"query": "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/queries/queries/my_query.sql"}, templates_exts=[".sql"])
    def test(**context):
        query = context["templates_dict"]["query"]
        bq_client = bigquery.Client()
        bq_client.query(query).result()

    test()
```

For older versions:

```py
class MyCustomOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ("query",)
    template_ext = (".sql",)
    
    def __init__(self, query, **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomOperator, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.query = query

    def execute(self, context):
        bq_client = bigquery.Client()
        bq_client.query(self.query).result()
with DAG(
    'test',
    schedule_interval = None,
    start_date = datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    user_defined_macros = {
        "MY_MACRO": "Hello World"
    }
) as dag:
    test = MyCustomOperator(task_id="test", query="test.sql")
```

Comment: Upvoting for detailed answer, but I am still on version 2.3 and the other one was simple to follow and implement