# When will airflow 2.5.* be available in Cloud Composer images?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I see airflow 2.5.0 was released on 2022-12-02.
When will it be available in cloud composer images ?

I want to iterate over a list of items output from a previous task to create dynamic task_group, similar to what is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74244254/how-to-use-dynamic-task-mapping-with-taskgroups)
I understand the implementation of the expand() method for task_groups is only available from airflow 2.5.
Therefore I would like to know when this will become available in Cloud Composer

```py
    @dag(
        'my_dag',
        schedule = None,
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_dag_args
    )
    def taskflow():
        @task
        def generate_data() -> List[str]:
            return ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
        
        @task_group
        def task_group_tasks(d):
            task_1  = BashOperator(task_id=f'task_1_{d}', bash_command='exit 0')
            task_2  = BashOperator(task_id=f'task_2_{d}', bash_command='exit 0')
            task_1 >> task_2
    
        list_data = generate_data()

        task_group_tasks.expand(data=list_data)

    dag = taskflow()
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the latest Airflow version that is currently available with Cloud Composer images is [`airflow-2.4.3`](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions#images). There is no announcement yet regarding its(airflow-2.5.*) usability with Cloud Composer. Meanwhile, you can visit the [Cloud Composer release notes](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes) from time to time to keep you posted. Also, you can check the [Airflow release notes](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/release_notes.html).

Comment: Update! As of April 25, according to the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes#April_25_2023) Airflow 2.5.1 is available in Composer! :)